# Disallow Prefix on certain cachmekey's larval

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

We have a microservice application, and in rare occasions we use the same cache item across multiple microservices. This sounds funny, but laravel adds the application name as a prefix. We want to prevent that for these application wide cache items.

How to disable the laravel application cache prefix?

So this:

```
Cache::remember('campaigns:global:discovery:en', 3600, 'TEST');
```

**Becomes this:**

microservice_1_cache:campaigns:global:discovery:en

**And should be:**

campaigns:global:discovery:en

Comment: `config/cache.php`; look for the item labeled `prefix`.

Comment: Is that available in Lumen? You are fast BTW ;)

Comment: No idea; nothing in the post said Lumen, and Laravel now recommends dropping Lumen. See the red box on https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/9.x.

Comment: So adding a prefix works, but simply adds another prefix. `'prefix'=>'global:'`
becomes 

`global_cache:microservice_1_cache:campaigns:global:discovery:en`

Comment: Don't add a prefix; try setting it to null or `''`.

Comment: Also, see `config/database.php`; `redis.options.prefix` appears to also set a prefix.

Comment: Doesn't work for both

Comment: Even if we set a global prefix, it still adds the application name afterwords

Comment: In both Laravel and Lumen you can use `config(['cache.prefix' => '']);` before caching this object and then revert back to what it was after